# Filtering option is not functioning when the selection of the criteria is other way round

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am facing a strange issue here and really not sure why this is happening. So need help form you all.

When you run the below app and select "Correlation" from the dropdown, there is no plot displayed. But when you select "Trend" First and then select "Correlation" the plot is getting displayed. Very strange here. Not sure what wrong I am doing here. Please help

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
    runtime: shiny
    theme: cosmo
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
Copy_of_mill_para <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1505779200, 1505779500, 1505779800, 
1505780100, 1505780400, 1505780700, 1505781000, 1505781300, 1505781600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), A = c(42, 
40, 41, 45, 25, 39, 44, 25, 39), B = c(27, 36, 40, 31, 44, 34, 
39, 44, 41), C = c(39, 42, 33, 26, 29, 42, 24, 34, 35)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
Copy_of_mill_para1 <- Copy_of_mill_para %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -Date)
```

Summary
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("c", "Filter1", choices = c("","Trend","Correlation"))
output$filter_2 <- renderUI({
    if (input$c == "") {
      return()
    } else if (input$c == "Trend") {
      label = "Trend"
      selectInput("b",
                label,
                choices = c("ALL", levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable))))
    } else {
      label = "First Variable"
      selectInput("b",
                label,
                choices = c(levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable))))
    }

  })

output$filter_3 <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if (input$c == "Trend"|input$c == "") {
      return()
    } else {
      selectInput("a",
                "Second Variable",
                choices = c(levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable))))
    }
  })

uiOutput("filter_2")
uiOutput("filter_3")
output$filter_7 <- renderUI({
  if (input$c == "Trend")
  radioButtons("r",h5("Highlight"),choices = list("No", "Yes"),selected = "No", inline = T)  
})
uiOutput("filter_7")
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
output$g1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$c)
    if (input$c == "Trend") {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1
    }
    if (input$c == "Trend" & input$b != "ALL") {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1 %>% filter(variable == input$b)
    }
    if (input$c == "Correlation"){
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para
    }

    if (input$c == "Trend" & input$r != "Yes") {
        ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
            geom_line(size =  .2)
    } 
   else if (input$c == "Trend"& input$r == "Yes") {
        ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
            geom_line(size =  .2)+geom_point(data = plot_data %>% filter(variable == "A"),aes(x=Date, y = value),color='red',size=3)
    }
  else if (input$c == "Correlation") {
        req(input$a)
        req(input$b)
        ggplot(plot_data, aes_string(x = input$b, y = input$a)) +
            geom_point()
    }
})

plotOutput("g1")
```
````

Comment: Thanks. @Ben What do you suggest ?:)

Comment: Nope. I tried but still the same

Comment: Wanted to check as per your comment, if correlation is selected first, input$r is not there. But if I select it post selecting "Trend", the plot is displayed even though input$r is not there

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to consolidate your `if` statements, and add `req(input$...)` to make sure those inputs exist before evaluation (will be NULL initially).

In addition, it threw an error checking for an "ALL" variable to make the correlation plot - you can first make sure the input values are contained within (using `%in%`) the data before plotting (added statement for this).

`output$g1` will get called twice as you change `selectInput` c with the dependencies. One way to address this is to use `isolate` on input(s) you don't want to trigger `output$g1`.

But please see if this is helpful. A lot depends on what you want your final outcome to look like.

````
### Chart A

```{r}
output$g1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$b, input$c)

    if (input$c == "Trend") {
      req(input$r)

      if (input$b != "ALL") {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1 %>% filter(variable == input$b)
      } else {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1
      }

      if (input$r != "Yes") {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
          geom_line(size =  .2)
      } else {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
          geom_line(size =  .2)+geom_point(data = plot_data %>% filter(variable == "A"),aes(x=Date, y = value),color='red',size=3)
      }
    }

    if (input$c == "Correlation") {
      req(input$a)

      plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para
      if (input$b %in% Copy_of_mill_para1$variable && input$a %in% Copy_of_mill_para1$variable) {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes_string(x = input$b, y = input$a)) +
          geom_point()
      }
    }

    p
})

plotOutput("g1")
````

Here is the full Rmarkdown with some consolidation of inputs and other minor modifications:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
    runtime: shiny
    theme: cosmo
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
Copy_of_mill_para <- structure(list(
  Date = structure(c(1505779200, 1505779500, 1505779800, 1505780100, 1505780400, 1505780700, 1505781000, 1505781300, 1505781600), 
                   class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
  A = c(42, 40, 41, 45, 25, 39, 44, 25, 39), 
  B = c(27, 36, 40, 31, 44, 34, 39, 44, 41), 
  C = c(39, 42, 33, 26, 29, 42, 24, 34, 35)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

Copy_of_mill_para1 <- Copy_of_mill_para %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Date)
```

Summary
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("c", "Filter1", choices = c("", "Trend", "Correlation"))

output$filter_2 <- renderUI({
  if (input$c == "") {
    return()
  } else if (input$c == "Trend") {
    div(
      selectInput("b", "Trend", choices = c("ALL", levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable)))),
      radioButtons("r", h5("Highlight"), choices = list("No", "Yes"), selected = "No", inline = T)  
    )
  } else {
    div(
      selectInput("b", "First Variable", choices = c(levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable)))),
      selectInput("a", "Second Variable", choices = c(levels(factor(Copy_of_mill_para1$variable))))
    )
  }
})

uiOutput("filter_2")
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
output$g1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$b)

    if (isolate(input$c) == "Trend") {
      req(input$r)

      if (input$b != "ALL") {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1 %>% filter(variable == input$b)
      } else {
        plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para1
      }

      if (input$r != "Yes") {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
          geom_line(size =  .2)
      } else {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Date, y = value, color = variable)) +
          geom_line(size =  .2)+geom_point(data = plot_data %>% filter(variable == "A"),aes(x=Date, y = value),color='red',size=3)
      }
    }

    if (isolate(input$c) == "Correlation") {
      req(input$a)

      plot_data <- Copy_of_mill_para
      if (input$b %in% Copy_of_mill_para1$variable && input$a %in% Copy_of_mill_para1$variable) {
        p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes_string(x = input$b, y = input$a)) +
          geom_point()
      }
    }

    p
})

plotOutput("g1")
```
````

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort. I will check this. Quick question, may I know what is isolate doing here?

Comment: `isolate` allows you to access a reactive value or expression, but not to take a dependency on it. that way, you can use `input$c` but if that input changes, it would not execute the output. you already have other inputs (a and b) that would trigger the output. this way, output is displayed once and not twice

Comment: I just tried this. I got the output. I removed isolate but still it is working. Just wanted to see how isolate would make a difference. Also in the last if statement you have only given ````req(input$a)```` . but ````req(input$b)```` is not required?

Comment: it does work without `isolate`, but if you watch carefully (or use debugger) you can detect it plots twice instead of once. as for `req(input$b)` this is at the top of the function already and only needed once. all plots rely on `b` so put this first.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Plots twice instead of once? When and where exactly?

Comment: it's just a split second difference. it plots right on top of each other. say, you select 'trend', it shows a plot. then, if you change to 'correlation' using `input$c` - `input$c` causes `output$g1` to update and show plot1. the other inputs (a and b) are dependent on `input$c`, and will get updated as well appropriately. once that happens (almost immediately), that will also trigger `output$g1` a second time and it will immediately afterwards draw plot2.